# How to get an Xpages variable to retain value

Tags: java, xpages

A Java class in an Xpage application is technically working but a second parsing of a string to Long is causing enormous error messages in the logs.  I did not develop this application and just trying to maintain it.  I understand all the mechanics of what is occurring inside the first try - catch block and understand the scope of the variable "retval" in the first try-catch block.  But I do not understand why the developer has created a second try-catch block and again parses the parameter named "value" which by this time is empty and this is what is causing the problem.  I have attempted to amend the scope of the retval variable and adjust the code to have one try-catch block but it causes errors.  Why is the second parsing being processed and how can I stop it being an empty value?

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
   String value) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     UIOutputLabel label = (UIOutputLabel) FacesUtilExtsn
        .getLabelFor(component);
     UIInput uiinput = (UIInput) component;
       if (UiValidationTools.doValidation((UIInputText)component, 
         context)) {
         String msg = UiValidationTools.getFriendlyname((UIInput) 
           component);
         try {

            Long retval = Long.parseLong(value);

            if (value.isEmpty()) {

              if(msg!=null){
                  msg+=" - Value must be a valid number eg 3";
                  }else{
                  msg="Value must be a valid number eg 3";
                  }
                  uiinput.setValid(false);
                  FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                   msg);
                  throw new ConverterException(message);
             }

             Integer max = UiValidationTools.getMax((UIInputText)
              component);
             Integer min = UiValidationTools.getMin((UIInputText) 
              component);

             if (min != null) {
               if (retval < min.doubleValue()) {
                if(msg!=null){
                  msg+=" - Value must be between " + min + " and " + max;
                  }else{
                  msg="Value must be between " + min + " and " + max;
                  }
                uiinput.setValid(false);
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                   msg);
                throw new ConverterException(message);
                }
             }

             if (max != null) {
               if (retval > max.doubleValue()) {
                 if(msg!=null){
                  msg+=" - Value must be between " + min + " and " + max;
                  }else{
                  msg="Value must be between " + min + " and " + max;
                 }
                 uiinput.setValid(false);
                 FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                  msg);
                 throw new ConverterException(message);
                }
              }
              // At this point the the parameter named "value" has 
              //content as inside scope
            return retval;

        } catch (NumberFormatException nume) {
          System.out.println("Getting caught here...");
          uiinput.setValid(false);
          if(msg!=null){
            msg+=" - Not a valid number: "
             + nume.getMessage();
           }else{
            msg="Not a valid number: "
              + nume.getMessage();
          }
         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(msg);
          nume.printStackTrace();
       throw new ConverterException(message);
     }
  }else{
    System.out.println("Value is "+value);

 }
 try{

   // At this point the parameter named "value" is empty as outside scope
   // and this is what is causing issues as it is empty
   Long retval = Long.parseLong(value);
   return retval;
   }catch(NumberFormatException numfe){
     System.out.println("Our error has been caught*!*!*!*!*!*!*!*!");
     numfe.printStackTrace();
     return new Long(0);
   }

 }
```

Comment: Good material for http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: Anyway, what is exact value of "value" parameter? As a String it can be `null` or "", what is not covered...

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth the "value" parameter has processes to ensure it is intially entered as a 6 figure number, so up to 999999.  It is stored as a string in the Lotus Notes Document but for reasons too long to be explained here it is handled as a number too and because it can be up to 999999 it is to large for an integer and so parsed as a long.  The problem occurs when the "value" is parsed a second time it is empty after being returned as the retval of the function the first time

Comment: Please show some snippet how is it called "second time" - once returned as Long, how it comes to be String again?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth I have posted the entire class procedure and it is parsed a second time about eight lines from the bottom.  I am not that experienced in XPages and cannot understand why the developer has parsed it twice - especially when both catch statements handle the same error really.  When the "value" parameter is parsed the first time the "value" parameter retains its contents until the first "return retval" because I put a system out just before the return retval and the "value" still had its contents